# Zookeeper ephemeral node usage from bash script

Tags: bash, apache-zookeeper

I have a typical task queue setup where a pool of hosts are taking task from queue and completing them. For mutual exclusive lock on task, I am considering zookeeper ephemeral nodes.

bash sample psuedocode:

```bash
# 1. peek at queue (got task1)
# 2. create a zookeeper ephemeral node
zookeeper-client create -e /tasks/task1
# complete the task
# release the ephemeral node ??
```

My understanding is that step 2 will release ephemeral node and it will be deleted after some timeout irrespective of whether my task finishes or not.

How can I create a scope in bash to so that ephemeral node is released only upon task completion?

Comment: 15 years ago when I last poked at Zookeeper (I've been on the RAFT crew since), my recollection was that an ephemeral node expired the moment the client it belonged to disconnected (supporting this properly being part of why a dedicated non-HTTP wire protocol was in use), so I'm surprised to have a `zookeeper-client` program that exits yet has ephemeral nodes it created persist.

Comment: I will note that if you're using a modern competitor to zookeeper, you'd run something like `consul lock /tasks/task1 command-to-run arg1 arg2...`, and the lock would be held as long as `command-to-run` remained active (and losing the lock prematurely would cause `command-to-run` to be signaled and killed).

Comment: actually, it looks to me like the behavior I remembered still holds today: when you use `create -e` inside zkshell, the node is released the moment that copy of zkshell exits; so you can't usefully use it to make a lock you intend to hold without using a bash coprocess or similar extension to make the zkshell instance long-running. Not actually adding an answer without a doc review or practical test I don't have time for, though.